# How to Check data exists in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How we can check whether the data exists in the SharedPreferences.if exists then start new activity?

Answer (score 5):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("application_settings", 0);
int id = prefs.getInt("id", 0);
if(id > 0) {
  startActivity(new Intent(CurrentCLass.this, NextClass.class));
}
```

Comment: If the id exists you should then use an intent to start a new activity. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: So this code will be in the onCreate function or some other function.I am new in android please help me

Comment: In order for this to be effective, you have to first update your sharedpreferences ie put in the value of id.Then, place this code wherever you want to move to another activity on the basis of the value of id.

Comment: My question is that when first time application will run i will save the information and start a new activity,after that i want to check only if the information exists start the activity .So for second time where i will put this code

Comment: the same place where you save the information in the first run.

Comment: where i can see whether SharedPreferences  data has been saved

Comment: How should i close this Intent in the destroy function.Please suggest.

Comment: public void startingActivity(String HOST_URL) {
  Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
          Uri.parse(HOST_URL));
           startActivity(viewIntent);
           finish();}

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you retrieve the data, you always need to supply a default parameter to return if the data doesn't exist, so for example

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
int data = pref.getInt("key",-1);
```

then `data` will be `-1` if the preference value for "key" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preferences.contains("yourKey")){
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple Solution. Get Data From Shared Preference. If Data Not Found Then It Returns `null` So Check if String Variable get null or any other Value.

```
File f = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/shared_prefs/mypref.xml");
        if(f.exists())
        { 

            String user=mypref.getString("UserName", null);
            if(user!=null){     
                                   //do stuff`enter code here
            }
        }
```